# Reading a certain number of lines from a file

Tags: scala, io

```
def getLinesFromFile(file:File, linesToGet:Int): List[String] ={
    val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(file)
    val lb = ListBuffer[String]()
    try {
      val lines = bufferedSource.getLines()
      var counter = 0
      while (lines.hasNext && counter < linesToGet) {
        counter += 1
        lb.append(lines.next())
      }
    } finally {
      bufferedSource.close()
    }
    lb.toList
  }
```

I am trying to retrieve a certain amount of lines from a read text file, and return each line as a List back to the user. Validation for the file actually being a .txt file is done prior to this call, and I can say with certainty that each line won't be longer than @500 characters.

My primary concern is I'm wondering if there any reason this code would create any memory leaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That implementation is very procedural.  `getLines()` returns an `Iterator`, which supports a [`take(n)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html#take(n:Int):Iterator[A]) method.

```
def getLinesFromFile(file:File, linesToGet:Int): List[String] = {
  val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile(file)
  try {
    bufferedSource.getLines.take(linesToGet).toList
  } finally {
    bufferedSource.close
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, changed! Thanks. However, not quite where I was looking for help. Does calling `getLines` load the entire file into memory? And at what point is the buffered source fully closed, and no longer needed in memory? I'm worried that even though I'm calling `close`, it isn't actually closing until some time later, perhaps via the GC, is this right?

Comment: From the [Scala FAQ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/stream-view-iterator.html): "Iterators are non-strict: they are computed on-demand instead of in advance. … An iterator can only be used once because it is a _traversal pointer_ into a collection, and not a collection in itself." It's just an elegant way to do what your `counter` did. Question is, does `BufferedSource` load the entire file into memory? It shouldn't. If you are really stingy, you could set the buffer size when calling `Source.fromFile()`. If you're paranoid, run your code under `strace` to see what data got read.

Comment: What makes you think that calling `close()` doesn't close the file handle?

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. What's making me paranoid is my system at large, when reading several very large files (1 gig each or more, sometimes 5 at a time), my entire drive slows to a crawl about 70% of the way through, and persists even though I have confirmation the program has closed after a `System.exit(1)` . And I'm just not sure what it would be, but an issue like this was the source of the problem in the past.

Comment: Well, you did ask for a `List`, which does store all its data. If your system runs out of physical memory, it starts swapping memory out to disk ("thrashing"). Then, after the memory hog program ends, the OS would tend to swap in the data to memory again, which is also I/O intensive. But that's my speculation based on your description. You shouldn't speculate either; use a memory profiler if you want to understand what your problem is.

Comment: At what point is the returned List dumped from memory? I think I was using it in one call and then moving on. And I was only ever calling this method asking for 2 lines on 5 files. Those lines were only about 500 chars each, so at most, it would have been 10 lines of 500 chars. Would that still cause something so severe?

Comment: The List is freed from memory when the garbage collector runs, and there are no remaining references to the list.